# Is it possible to use @Transational worked in Spring, Eclipselink &Tomcat environment?

Tags: spring, tomcat, transactions, annotations, eclipselink

HiAll, 
I was confused by the EclipseLink for Tomcat [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Tomcat_Web_Tutorial#Non-JTA_Datasource) saying:

> Limitations to JPA: 
>   No @PersistenceContext injection of a container managed persistence unit is available - use Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(JTA_PU_NAME)

and, also by this [question&answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049105/eclipselink-with-spring-cant-persist-into-db/4051527#4051527):

> but the typical JPA configuration in Spring looks like this, so you don't need to create EntityManager manually :
>   @PersistenceContext
>   private EntityManager em;

So, the question is: may I use this annotation @PersistenceContext for the entityManager to be sure that it will be created automatically and I dont need to create it manually?

Currently my @Transactional annotation does not work properly and I'm afraid it is because of creating the entity manager manually!

Please, need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EclipseLink documentation says that `@PersistenceContext` is not handled by Tomcat on its own. However, if you use Spring, `@PersistenceContext` is handled by Spring, so that you can use it.

**See also:**

- [13.5 JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa)

Comment: then, could you also specify, what the difference between adding annotation @PersistenceContext on EntityManager and  EntityManagerFactory ?

Comment: @PersistenceContext on EntityManagerFactory won't work. For EntityManagerFactories you have to use @PersistenceUnit

Comment: @dunni thank you very much... some documentation is awful then, stating its possible